# How can I get my own Facebook "news feed" via Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm interesting About an Ability to get my own feed
(not my posts, only just like I login to my Facebook account and see post from people who I follow).

I have search about this issues, but did not find any results.

please advise

Comment: You can't. There is no API for that.

Comment: Hi @WizKid. thanks for the answer. but As I know It was available on 2.1virsion

Comment: Graph API 2.1 was released in August 7, 2014 and was removed on October 31, 2016. And you are correct. It has existed before. That doesn't mean it exists now.